# Create col based on matching historical records from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I have two dataframes, `df_a` and `df_b`:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({
    'date_a': [
        datetime.datetime(2020,1,9,1,1,1,1),
        datetime.datetime(2020,1,4,1,1,1,1),
        datetime.datetime(2020,1,1,1,1,1,1),
        datetime.datetime(2020,1,6,1,1,1,1)
    ],
    'ID': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'a']
})

df_b = pd.DataFrame({
    'date_b': [
        datetime.datetime(2020,1,8,1,1,1,1),
        datetime.datetime(2020,1,5,1,1,1,1),
        datetime.datetime(2020,1,5,1,1,1,1)
    ],
    'ID_1': ['a', 'b', 'f'],
    'ID_2': ['d', 'a', 'c']
})
```

And I want to create a new column (`V`) in `df_a` that is `True` if there is a record in `df_b` where `df_b.ID_1` or `df_b.ID_2` matches `df_a.ID` **AND** `df_b.date_b` is less then or equal to `df_a.date_a`. The result would look like this:

```
df_a
    date_a                      ID  V
0   2020-01-09 01:01:01.000001  a   True
1   2020-01-04 01:01:01.000001  a   False
2   2020-01-01 01:01:01.000001  c   False
3   2020-01-06 01:01:01.000001  a   True
```

Basically, I want to check, for each row in `df_a` if there is a historical record for that `ID`. Hope the question makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to melt `df_b`, then do cross merge on `ID` and query:

```
unique_id = (df_b.melt('date_b', value_name='ID')
                .drop('variable',axis=1)
                .sort_values('date_b')
                .drop_duplicates('ID'))

(df_a.merge(unique_id,
           on='ID',
           how='left'
          )
     .assign(V=lambda x: x.date_b <= x.date_a)
     .drop('date_b',axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
                      date_a ID      V
0 2020-01-09 01:01:01.000001  a   True
1 2020-01-04 01:01:01.000001  a  False
2 2020-01-01 01:01:01.000001  c  False
3 2020-01-06 01:01:01.000001  a   True
```

Another way is to use `merge_asof`, but first you also need to filter `df_b` for the minimum date in each id:

```
# unique_id as above
(pd.merge_asof(df_a.sort_values('date_a'), 
              unique_id, 
              left_on='date_a',
              right_on='date_b', 
              by='ID')
   .assign(V=lambda x: x.date_b.notnull())
   .drop('date_b', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
                      date_a ID      V
0 2020-01-01 01:01:01.000001  c  False
1 2020-01-04 01:01:01.000001  a  False
2 2020-01-06 01:01:01.000001  a   True
3 2020-01-09 01:01:01.000001  a   True
```